# MariaDB connection very slow in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mariadb

I'm currently using MariaDB version 10.5.12 and the mariadb-connector-nodejs package to interact with it from NodeJS

The pool is created as such

```js
const pool = MariaDB.createPool({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST, 
    user: process.env.DB_USER, 
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    connectionLimit: 25
});
```

A simple request such as `connection.Query("SELECT * FROM Users");` Where the users table only contains 5 users can take anywhere between 90ms and 650ms

profiling the query in MariaDB says the query itself only takes a few nanoseconds.

The time a request takes seems to be pretty random, the first request could be 100ms and the second one right after using the same connection could take 600ms which I feel is way too high for a query that takes less than a millisecond to process.

But I'm unable to find where the issue is coming from, I have tried doing all the changes mysqltuner recommended, I've tried disabling name resolve with no visible speedup (I assume the requests are being cached as all requests come from the same ip)

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after min 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/a7p90m6b
https://pastebin.com/0e94nyKh
https://textbin.net/raw/owftmhn1u9
https://pastebin.com/raw/7zx4C3Z0

Comment: Any chance you could post results of htop or top for your OS command prompt?  Could you post TEXT results of EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM Users; and SHOW CREATE TABLE Users:  Thank you.  Workload analysis will begin after posting of aditiional requests.  Thank you for data posted on Oct 8, 2021.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/WfDRGJeL and https://pastebin.com/0fqaqkQh

Comment: Thanks for your data.  Does your server have any SSD or NVME devices for your data tables?

Comment: the main and only drive Is an SSD from what I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

top indicates there is NO Swap space available.
Consider enabling 6G of swap space to survive busy situations with minimal delay and a surviving system.

Please share the code generally used to Connect, Process, Close connections.
Your threads_connected count indicates the Close is being missed and has left 83 threads connected in 10 days.

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section,

```
log_error=/var/log/mysql/mariadb-error.log  # from 0 to allow viewing ERRORS detected.
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm=1  # from 0 percent to enable pre-flushing
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=1  # from 90 percent to minimize innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty of 367.
innodb_adaptive_hash_index=ON  # from OFF to minimize deadlocks
max_connect_errors=10  # from 100 to frustrate hackers/crackers after 10 attempts.
connect_timeout=30  # from 10 seconds to be more tolerant of connection attempts.
```

Observations,
connections were 120,604 in 10 days and you had 28984 aborted_connects about 1/4 of the events.  You must have a lot of unhappy people trying to use your system or they are hackers trying to break in.

View profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.